# How to SSL with Amazon Linux AMI Ec2?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, installation

I'm using Aws AIM. So, how to install openSSL? I have no idea how to do it.

It is because I want to compile node.js with ssl so that I can have crypto support.

I tried pkg-config..etc from here: Node.js installation: openssl not installed

however, apt-get doesn't exist. pkg-config doesn't recognize the -lssl

I totally have no idea..

Answer (score 1):

The "Official" Amazon Linux Images are based off a CentOS image, so you want to use yum as your package manager, not apt-get.

Comment: there are a ton of community ami's that are based of ubuntu also

Comment: thanks.  i got it working now. .thanks.   basically, I need to install openssl_devl   , the development tool. :)